# wxWidgets Linker Error after including a Panel when using minimal

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, linker-errors

I've come across an interesting problem and I've basically been banging my head against the wall for the last two hours trying to figure it out. My GUI was working fine until I decided to include a panel object for drawing a simple graph, so I created a class

```
class dataPanel : public wxPanel
{

public:
    dataPanel(wxFrame* parent);


    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
```

Then I included the following line of code in my frame:

```
dataPanel * dataDisp = new dataPanel(this);
```

And now I get the following linker error:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl
>   dataPanel::dataPanel(class wxFrame *)"
>   (??0dataPanel@@QEAA@PEAVwxFrame@@@Z) referenced in function "public:
>   __cdecl MyFrame::MyFrame(class wxString const &)" (??0MyFrame@@QEAA@AEBVwxString@@@Z)

Take the above line of code out, and it compiles fine. I have my menu structure, tool bars, and everything, but when I try to create a panel, I get linker errors. I've opened up sample projects that use panels. I've compiled them no issue. I compared their settings to my settings and it looks like they are the same, so I'm not sure where the disconnect is.

Has anyone else experienced this? I started this current project by using the "minimal.sln" that comes with wxWidgets.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you define your ctor anywhere? The linker error seems to quite straightforwardly indicate that you simply forgot to do it...

Comment: @StephenHamrick, in addition to what Vadim said -  did you include the additional files into the project/solution?

Comment: Okay so after I posted I turned my computer off for the night. When I tried to log back in my Hard Drive had failed. I restored a back up to a new hard drive and now it works... So I'm guessing it was some how related to my hard drive failing...